# How can I add gems to my vendor/cache directory in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I use EngineYard, and I have a deployment that is failing. I am getting this message:

```
Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
Could not find rspec-core-2.6.0.rc2 in any of the sources
```

How do I make sure those gems get in that directory?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Bundler ships a command which explicitly creates this cache

```
bundle package
```

After you've done this bundle install will check and keep the vendor/cache directory up to date.

If you then want to install the gems on a machine without checking on rubygems, you just run

```
bundle install --local
```

However, beware, if you are upgrading gems frequently (like I do every time a subrelease of Rails comes out), your vendor/cache can quickly grow.

My current project's git repository is 80mb, of which more than 30mb is data stored in vendor/cache.

It seemed like a good idea to speed up deploys,
but overall its just made our repository much bigger.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone else is experiencing this when deploying with Capistrano, this solved it for me:
https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1454

Having an empty vendor/cache directory was causing the problem in my case.

Solution was to **delete** (not just ignore the contents of!) the **vendor/cache** directory from version control and commit + deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Its `bundle cache` now for anyone wondering

> ```
>    bundle cache(1) bundle-cache.1.html
>          Package the .gem files required by your application into the vendor/cache directory (aliases: bundle package, bundle pack)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

bundle package without installing the downloading gems.

```
bundle package --no-install
```

Answer (score -4):

I figured this out. I just typed:

```
bundle
```

at the command line, and it added the missing gems.

Comment: Just `bundle` is equivalent to `bundle install`, which does not, in itself put gems in vendor/cache.  You need to use `bundle package`